# PfSense IPv6 network configuration

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, pfsense

I am trying to create an IPv6 network in VMware ESx by using a pfsense virtual machine and a windows 10 client. I have a network interface where I connect to a pure IPv6 Vlan which provides me with an IP via DCHP6.
My goal is to configure the firewall to act as a router that will allow the machines that are connected to my lan interface to have IPv6 internet access.

The IP address that I get from the Vlan is /64.
From my research I am not sure how I am supposed to configure my LAN subnets and how I should go about subnetting the IP that I am given. Moreover, I don't know if I should try to have DCHP6 or SLAAC on my LAN.

Basically I need help with configuring pfsense LAN network so that my machines can access the internet. Any tips or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The IP address that I get from the Vlan is /64.

No, that sounds very much like it's just an /128 *out of* a /64 subnet.

It works just like in IPv4 – the system might show your address as "192.168.1.7/24", but that doesn't mean you get the entire /24 to yourself, you only got a single address from the common /24-sized pool.

In order to get a *whole* /64 prefix (or another desired prefix size), you need either DHCPv6-**PD** (prefix delegation) or have the network admin manually route a prefix to you.

> how I should go about subnetting the IP that I am given

You can't subnet a single address, it is already the smallest unit. You can only subnet networks/ranges/prefixes, so first use DHCPv6-PD to obtain one, or contact your network admin.

(If DHCPv6-PD is available, pfSense has the "Track interface" option which automatically assigns subnet prefixes to your LAN and VLAN interfaces, saving you most of the configuration work.)

The recommended IPv6 subnet size is /64, so always start with getting a prefix large enough to have a sufficient number of /64's. For example, try obtaining a /60 or even a /56.

Among other reasons why it's "recommend", you'll find that SLAAC-based address assignment is still almost universally implemented to only work with /64s (with OpenBSD being a rare exception).

(This doesn't apply to DHCPv6-only networks, or to non-broadcast networks such as VPNs. Any subnet size is valid as long as the software is willing to use it. Still, for consistency's sake, /64 is always the first choice for a subnet allocation.)

> Moreover, I don't know if I should try to have DCHP6 or SLAAC on my LAN.

You can have both. Note that DHCPv6 normally doesn't distribute a "default gateway" – you still need to run Router Advertisements alongside, even though you're not required to set the "SLAAC allowed" bit in them.

But remember that many systems don't support DHCPv6-based address assignment (though they might still be able to get additional information from DHCP), so you'll need SLAAC to support those devices.

Comment: Wow! Everything you said makes so much sense and I understand why what I was trying didn't work. I will talk with the admin about this issues! Thank you so much for your help!